# Getting Cannot modify Error at wp-admin in inspect element

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Yes, This is error little different well in Inspect element Source Tab of Google Chrome(check at firefox too).I search everywhere for solution but could not find any thing helpful
My Wordpress Theme So shows wp-admin in inspect mode

```
wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=df_dynamic_css&ver=3.9.1
wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=df_dynamic_js&ver=1
```

but in df dynamic css in body section in it

```
 /* ==========================================================================
   Body
   ========================================================================== */
   body { 
    background-color: #dddddd; 
    }
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/*****/public_html/wp-content/themes/dialy-theme/lib/css/dynamic-css.php:45) in <b>/home/*****/public_html/wp-content/themes/dialy-theme/lib/css/fonts.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />`
```

Well it shows directory in source I Don't know why it is coming in inspect mode
dynamic-css.php

```
/* ==========================================================================
   Body
   ========================================================================== */
<?php if($bodyBgType=="pattern") { ?>
body { 
    background-color: #ddd; 
    background-image: url(<?php echo THEME_IMAGE_URL;?>patterns/<?php echo $bodyPattern;?>.png)
}
<?php } elseif($bodyBgType=="color") { ?>
body { 
    background-color: #<?php echo $bodyColor;?>; 
}
<?php } elseif($bodyBgType=="image") { ?>
body { 
    background-image: url(<?php echo $bodyImage;?>);
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center;
}
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your file `/home/*****/public_html/wp-content/themes/dialy-theme/lib/css/dynamic-css.php`, check if you have a trailing `?>` line. If so, remove it.